# Getting error when running XUnit.net msbuild task for Assemblies

Tags: xunit.net

I'm getting an error when running xunit.net tasks using MSBuild tasks, as detailed in the xunit wiki: http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUseMSBuild

My MSBuild file is:

```
<Project
    DefaultTargets="Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <UsingTask
    AssemblyFile="xunit.runner.msbuild.dll"
    TaskName="Xunit.Runner.MSBuild.xunit" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="..\**/*.tests.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Test">
    <xunit Assemblies="@(TestAssemblies)" xml="..\TestResults.xml" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

when I run the msbuild script the build runs successfully and my test results are returned (Test count, failure count etc).

However after displaying the results I get the message to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\My First Jenkins
>   Build\workspace\src\MyWeb App\Solution Items\xunit.msbuild" (default
>   target) (1) -> (Test target) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\My First Jenkins Build\workspace\src\MyWe
>   bApp\Solution Items\xunit.msbuild(14,5): error :
>   System.ArgumentException: Coul d not find file: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\My First Jenkins Build\wor
>   kspace\src\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Tests\obj\Debug\xunit.dll   C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\My First Jenkins Build\workspace\src\MyWe
>   bApp\Solution Items\xunit.msbuild(14,5): error :    at
>   Xunit.ExecutorWrapper..c tor(String assemblyFilename, String
>   configFilename, Boolean shadowCopy)   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\My First Jenkins Build\workspace\src\MyWe
>   bApp\Solution Items\xunit.msbuild(14,5): error :    at
>   Xunit.Runner.MSBuild.xun it.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFilename,
>   String configFilename, IRunnerLogge r logger)

I'm not sure why it's looking for xunit.dll, can anyone shed any light?  When I use `<xunit Assembly>` rather than `<xunit Assemblies>` it works okay.

Comment: exact message always helps but the specific version of xunit.dll you're building against needs to be in the obj dir alongside your `*.tests.dll` (and 95% sure there needs to be one beside `xunit.runner.msbuild.dll`). Reading your very last bit... When you look with ILSpy, what properties do you see on the `xunit` Task impl?

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I've added full error message. Used ILSpy to glimpse into it but can't see why it needs the xunit.dll, this is only when running for multiple assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that I was having was with my TestAssemblies element, updating it to the following has resolved the issue:

```
<TestAssemblies Include="..\**\bin\*\*.Tests.dll" />
```

I think something other my intended 'test' dlls were being picked up, which was causing xunit to look for xunit.dll.